# Finish function executing before proceeding

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that is validated upon submission, inside the form submit a function is called, the submit continues and doesn't wait for the function to finish. How do I fix this?

```
var clientaddress=false;

function checkaddress(callback){
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            clientaddress=false;
             callback(false);
        }
       else if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            clientaddress=true;
            callback(false);
       }
    }

 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery("#submitOrder").submit(function(){
        checkaddress(function(result) {

                    if (!result) { 
                        jAlert("Please enter a valid address!");
                        jQuery("#address").focus();
                        isValidation = 0; 

                    }
                });

       //other validation code that gets executed without waiting for checkaddress()
       //submit page
     })
```

I tried to make one function that calls both the address checker and a validation function, but still they do not wait for each other.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: the result of checkAddress is `asynchronous` (meaning it can return at any time in the future and hence doesn't block other code from carrying on) and thus you will have to make a callback from within `function(results, status){...` to then continue validation and potential submission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `geocode` function is async! Use a callback:

```
function checkaddress(callback){
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) { 
        if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            callback(false)
        } else if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            callback(true)
        }
    });
}
```

Then use this like:

```
checkaddress(function(result) {
    if (result) { 
        //result true! 
    } else { 
        //result false! 
    }

    //REST OF YOUR CODE GOES HERE, IF PUT OUTSIDE IT WILL EXECUTE WHILE CHECKADDRESS IS IN PROGRESS
});
```

Your `submit` function is also most likely running the default behavior, use `preventDefault`

```
jQuery("#submitOrder").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    //code
});
```

Comment: Note to OP : For a cleaner code (IMO), you can do : `callback(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)`.

Comment: It didnt work for me, it still continues to submit the page, any ideas?

Comment: @Digitalfortress -- Updated the answer with a possible fix - you also need to put all the code you want to run after the `geocode` function inside the callback you supply - else it wont wait.

Comment: @tymeJV sorry not following, how to put the code inside the callback?

Comment: @Digitalfortress -- Added a comment in the answer to show where code goes